# How to compare two dates if they are before and after the current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am working in an application where i am comparing selected date from  fullcalendar with current date where i need to check the selected date is less than the current date or advance the current date. What i have done i am posting here

```
var selectedDate = $('#selectedDate').val();
var today = new Date();
var str_date = selectedDate.split(',');

for(var i =0 ;i<str_date.length;i++){

    str_date[i] = str_date[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");

    if(str_date[i] <=today){
        alert('before date')
    }
}
```

This code is not working it is not able to check the date which is a back date or the date which is an advance date  from the calendar.Please someone help .

Comment: What is format of selectedDate?

Comment: @SarjanDesai 2015-10-19

Comment: @Subho better use timestamp to compare

Comment: `if( Date.parse( selectedDate ) <= today){}`

Answer (score 0):

Get date from `fullCalendar` and set `new Date()` hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 and create next day date and then compare date.

Check below snippet:

```js
var selectedDate = "2015-10-20";  // Replace with $('#selectedDate').val();
var today = new Date();
var selectedDate = new Date(Date.parse(selectedDate));
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
today.setMilliseconds(0);
var nextDay = new Date(today.getTime());
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
if(selectedDate < today) {
  snippet.log('Date is before');
} else if(selectedDate >= today && selectedDate < nextDay) {
  snippet.log('Date is today');
} else {
  snippet.log('Date is after');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

```
    var selectedDate = $('#selectedDate').fullCalendar('getDate').format();
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if(new Date(selectedDate)  <= currentDate ){
            alert('before date')
        }
```